# Escaping + and % for email in Regular expression using ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, email-validation

I am coding for Email validation which may take set of special characters. I could successfully add others to RegEx. However when I try for '+' and '%' it gives me an error.
I used '\' to allow special characters.

```
\+ --> adds a space removing + sign
\% --> removes 3rd char after % sign
```

Comment: 1. Show us your regex. 2. Show us the error.

Comment: 3. Use [UrlDecode](http://cfdocs.org/UrlDecode) to decode URL-encoded values. 4. Stop trying to re-invent an already functioning wheel - just use either `isValid('email',input)` or `ListLen(input,'@') EQ 2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for the suggestions.

It was an issue with URLDecode. I removed it and now I can escape '+'.

Comment: isValid('email',whatever) does not validate the .education domain like it should.

Answer (score 4):

ColdFusion has several built-in validation functions for things such as email addresses.  You could simply use something like:

```
<cfif IsValid("email", YourEmailVar)>
    <!--- do what you want for success here --->
<cfelse>
    <!--- do what you want for validation failure here --->
</cfif>
```

[Documentation for IsValid function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fb9.html)

The `IsValid` function will also allow you to use RegEx if you prefer.

*EDIT*

In order to validate variables from the URL scope simply prepend that to the variable name.  Like so:

```
<cfif IsValid("email", URL.YourURLEmailVar)>
```

Comment: This is a good solution if I have to validate form.
However, I am sending these values over url and checking for SQLi attacks.

So my URL checks and allows some of special characters based on id/ name.
In this case, I am allowing email to have some of the commonly used special characters that are used.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question.  We need more details to help you.  It is hard to tell what exactly you are trying to do.  This validation will work with any ColdFusion variable. It does not need to be a form variable, although it can be.

Comment: So my URL checks and allows some of special characters based on id/ name. In this case, I am allowing email to have some of the commonly used special characters that are used

Comment: SQL injection is avoided by using parameterised queries, via [cfqueryparam](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam).